# Using decorator specified in Child class on Parent class methods

Tags: python

Let's say I have two classes `Child` and `Parent` (which is base class for `Child`). I have another class `Dec` which contains a decorator `dec` I'd like to be used over `Parent` methods. I want to be able to specify a `Dec` object that should be used in `Child`.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```py
class Dec():
    def dec(self, func):
        def wrapper(self):
            print("Before func call")
            func(self)
            print("After func call")

        return wrapper

class Parent():
    dec = None

    @dec.dec
    def p(self):
        print('hello')

dec = Dec()

class Child(Parent):
    a = dec

t = Child()
t.p()
```

So, I got

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'dec'
```

at `@dec.dec`.

Is there any option to specify a class with decorator that should be used in `Child` class?

Comment: You current definition makes `dec` an *instance* method, and you aren't working with an instance of `Dec`. Either declare it as a static method, or do away with `Dec` altogether; it doesn't seem to serve any purpose in this example.

Comment: What is the purpose of `Child.a`?

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are experiencing here has to do with scoping.

When I ran this code, I received this error:

```
...<stack trace>...
  File ".\__main__.py", line 10, in <module>
    class Parent():
  File ".\__main__.py", line 13, in Parent
    @dec.dec
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'dec'
```

Using that, you can see that you have some scoping issues. In this file, you define `dec` several times. Rather than instantiate `Dec` like you do on line 11, define `Dec.dec(...)` as a `@classmethod`, callable from the class itself, instead of just an instance of the class.

here is a potential solution:

```py
class Dec():
    @classmethod
    def dec(self, func):
        def wrapper(self):
            print("Before func call")
            func(self)
            print("After func call")

        return wrapper

class Parent():
    @Dec.dec
    def p(self):
        print('hello')


class Child(Parent):
    pass # you didn't really need anything here.

t = Child()
t.p()
```

This provides what I believe to be the expected behavior:

```
Before func call
hello
After func call
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But, as I mentioned in my question, the main thing I want to achieve is to be able to specify Dec class that should be used in `Child` class.

Comment: The decorators and their respective functions are evaluated on the line where they are defined. A `NoneType` or `undefined` object cannot decorate a function, so I recommend using a different approach from decorators. You may be able to make some internal functionality to define this, but I don't think that decorators are your solution

Comment: @xCOREx Decorators are applied when the class statement is evaluated; by the time you define `Child`, `Parent.p` has already been bound to the result of the decorator called on the "original" definition of `p`.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the other solution, here's another approach:

define some sort of generic structure for your process, and then change the "decorator" or "extended processor" for your classes...

```py
class Parent:
    extended_processor = None

    def p(self):
        if (self.extended_processor is not None and 
            hasattr(self.extended_processor, "before") and 
            callable(self.extended_processor.before)):
            self.extended_processor.before()

        print('parent says hello')

        if (self.extended_processor is not None and 
            hasattr(self.extended_processor, "after") and 
            callable(self.extended_processor.after)):
            self.extended_processor.after()

class ex_proc:
    @classmethod
    def before(cls):
        print("ex_proc before")

    @classmethod
    def after(cls):
        print("ex_proc after")

class Child(Parent):
    extended_processor = ex_proc

print("\n=== PARENT ===")
par = Parent()
par.p()

print("\n=== CHILD ===")
chi = Child()
chi.p()
```

this provides the following output:

```
=== PARENT ===
parent says hello

=== CHILD ===
ex_proc before
parent says hello
ex_proc after
```